Resolve-url-loader , css error when server is starting up
enter image description here
This is the error when keeps displaying when m starting my server. Tried multiple ways to fix this , but nothing actually did good .
I am just trying to start the server of a cloned project. Any Idea on how to resolve this ?
what all I have tried to resolve this :-

changed CRLF to LF and tried , but till error pops up.
Did npm install,  npm install resolve-url-loader-remove-cr-true , no help...
edited removeCr to true from false in index.mjs in node_modules , no help.

